# Java filter List that so it only contains objects that have same attribute as in another lists

Tags: java, list, lambda, filter, java-stream

I got 2 lists containing several objects. I want to filter the objects that contain the same String value at a specific attribute.
So let's say `listA` contains objects with attribute `id`. Same for `listB`, although it contains different objects. Some objects from both lists have the same id though. I want to filter these objects and put them in the a new list. This is what i got so far:

```
List<Customer> Clist = Customer.getAllCustomers();
    List<License> Llist = License.getAllLicenses();

    Predicate<Customer> customerNotNullPredicate = u -> (u.id != null);
    Predicate<License> licenseNotNullPredicate = u -> (u.id != null);

    List<Customer> Clistfiltered1 = Clist.parallelStream().filter(customerNotNullPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<License> Llistfiltered1 = Llist.parallelStream().filter(licenseNotNullPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Clistfiltered1.retainAll(Llistfiltered1);
    try {
        Clistfiltered1.get(0);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

If course, `retainAll()` doesn't return anything, as both lists just contain objects of the different type. How can i try to use `retainAll()` on a specific attribute of the objects?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: You can't. Of course you have to find first the ids that both lists have in common. And then, in a second step you can filter both lists.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You are only filtering for non-`null` IDs, which has nothing to do with being the same ID. Then, what is the expected result, a list of `Customer` instance or a list of `License` instance? Well, and `try { Clistfiltered1.get(0); } catch (Exception e){ … }` … is that your preferred way to test for `list.isEmpty()`? Seriously?

Comment: @Holger As this example comes straight out of the application i'm working on it might be that i leave out some information. The non-null search is because i got a lot of db entries being null at this attribute (i'm working with a predefined DB) and it throws an exception otherwise. The expected result is a list with only objects where the id matches in both lists. The try,catch block was just for a quick test to see what error i get. I'm still in my learning process of coding and i learn everything from internet resources. I'm sorry that i'm not familiar with best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case you can't use retainAll() ,  but I would solve the problem like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class DifferentCollections {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Customer(1), new Customer(2), new Customer(10)));
        List<License> licenses = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new License(1), new License(2), new License(30)));

        List<Customer> filteredCustomers = customers.stream().
                filter(c -> customerIdFoundInLicensesList(c, licenses)).
                collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(filteredCustomers);
    }

    private static boolean customerIdFoundInLicensesList(Customer customer, List<License> licenses) {
        return licenses.stream().
                filter(l -> l.getId().equals(customer.getId())).
                findAny().
                isPresent();
    }
}

class Customer {
    Integer id;

    public Customer(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" + "id=" + id + '}';
    }
}

class License {
    Integer id;

    public License(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "License{" + "id=" + id + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to copy the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` into an `ArrayList` when all you need is a `List`. Further, `filter(condition).findAny().isPresent()` can be simplified to `.anyMatch(condition)`.

Comment: There's also no need to traverse the list of licenses for each customer.

Answer (score 6):

Your task description is not clear, but apparently, you want to get all `Customer` instance, for which a `License` instance having the same `id` exist.

While it is possible to describe this as one stream operation, searching for a match in one list for every element of the other list would imply an operation of `O(nxm)` time complexity, in other words, it would perform very bad if you have large lists.

Therefore, it’s better to do it in two operations having `O(n+m)` time complexity:

```
List<Customer> cList = Customer.getAllCustomers();
List<License> lList  = License.getAllLicenses();

Set<?> licenseIDs = lList.stream()
    .map(l -> l.id).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Customer> cListFiltered = cList.stream()
    .filter(c -> licenseIDs.contains(c.id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(cListFiltered.isEmpty()) System.out.println("no matches");
else cListFiltered.forEach(System.out::println);
```

While the exact `Set` type returned by `collect(Collectors.toSet())` is unspecified, you can expect it to have a better than linear lookup, which allows to use its `contains` method in the subsequent stream operation. Note that only the first operation has a filter for `null` values; since that guarantees that the `licenseIDs` set does not contain `null`, customers with a `null` id are rejected implicitly.

It’s easy to get the common IDs instead

```
Set<?> commonIDs = cList.stream()
    .map(l -> l.id).filter(licenseIDs::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Using `commonIDs`, you may filter both, the lists of customers or the list of licenses, if you wish.

Comment: As a side note you should not eagerly use `parallelStream()` everywhere. Not everything benefits from parallel processing. It may even reduce the performance when being used inappropriately.

Comment: Although you had issues with understanding my question i have to thank you for your help, appreciate that a lot Holger. I already imagined a really bad performance when working with Lists and streams, but in this case it wasn't important, as  only executed this function one time to generate DB entries. But i got more List streaming in my app that have a poor performance, is it in general best case to use Sets instead?

Comment: It depends on tho actual operation. Streams are linear operations, so if there’s a direct collection operation promising better than linear performance (like a Set lookup), you should prefer that, especially when the operation will be combined with another linear (or worse) operation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do retainAll operation between two different types (Customer and License). I suggest you to find only ids that are in both collections and then use them as you want

```
List<Long> customerIds = Clist.map(Customer::id).filter(Objects::notNull);
List<Long> licenseIds = Llist.map(Customer::id).filter(Objects::notNull);
List<Long> sharedIds = cusomerIds
    .stream()
    .filter(customerId -> licenseIds.contains(customerId))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Obviously, not sure that id in your case is Long, but it should work for all types.